# Implemention Ironsource to Flitter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, ironsource

I am using Ironsource in flutter [Here](https://developers.is.com/developer-docs/flutter/)

`ironsource_mediation: 1.1.0 google_mobile_ads: 2.3.0`

**buld.gradle(app):**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:18.0.1' 
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appset:16.0.2'

implementation 'com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:7.2.7' 
// Add AdMob and Ad Manager Network
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.4.0' 
implementation 'com.ironsource.adapters:admobadapter:4.3.34'
// Add Facebook Network
implementation 'com.ironsource.adapters:facebookadapter:4.3.38'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.12.0'
```

**buld.gradle:**

`repositories {google()mavenCentral()maven { url 'https://android-sdk.is.com/' }}`

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value= "@string/android__admob_ads_id_key" />
```

****But Ireceive this error:****

> E/flutter (12382): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)]
> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(ERROR, Activity is null, null,
> null) E/flutter (12382): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
> message_codecs.dart:653 E/flutter (12382): #1
> MethodChannel._invokeMethod platform_channel.dart:315 E/flutter
> (12382):  E/flutter (12382): I/flutter
> (12382): PlatformException(ERROR, Activity is null, null, null)

How can I implement and configure ironsource in flutter?